# .remove() method in Python for list of lists

Tags: python, list

I was trying to remove an element from multiple lists within a list using .remove() method, which I know works for lists. I also used list comprehension. As an example, consider:

```
abc = [["a","b"],["a","c"]]
bc = [apple.remove("a") for apple in abc]
print(bc)
```

It will return the output [None, None]. I am curious why does happen and also what is the method I can use to achieve my desired output of [["b"], ["c"]].

Comment: The return of list.remove is None therefore the output

Comment: Oh you are right... How to then remove a single element and yet output the desired the list?

Comment: Print(abc) instead of bc ?

Comment: Notice that with remove you are altering the original list, so just do what @PicxyB said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the output `[None, None]` because `list.remove()` operates in-place and modifies the original list. You have two options:

1. Just operate on the original list. Note that it is not a good practice to use a list-comprehension for its side-effects <sup>([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5753597/843953))</sup>, so we should just write a regular loop here:

```
>>> for apple in abc:
...    apple.remove("a")
```

Then, you can `abc` to see that you have the desired result:

```
>>> print(abc)
[['b'], ['c']]
```

---

2. Create a copy of the original lists, excluding the items to be removed:

```
>>> bc = [[item for item in apple if item != "a"] for apple in abc]
```

which gives you the desired output in `bc`, but leaves the original list unchanged:

```
>>> print(abc)
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c']]
>>> print(bc) 
[['b'], ['c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Remove](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)  is an [in-place operation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/inplace-operator-in-python)

you are changing the original abc data structure. to see the changes you should `print(abc)`